# Scan codes and showkey commend

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm using `showkey` command (on my Slackware 14.2) to get the pressed key `scan code`. When i press key the command returns two values in hex for e.g. for a *"p"* key it shows `0x19 0x99` Why there are two values not just the one as i pressed only one key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again the answer is right there in the [MAN page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey).

> When in the default keycode dump mode, showkey prints to the standard output the keycode number or each key pressed or released. The kind of the event, press or release, is also reported.